# Determine if Log4J root logger is on

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Is there a way to determine if the Root logger is on?

File `log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.rootLogger=OFF
```

I know that I can check if a level is on using:

```
LOG.isDebugEnabled()
```

But there doesn't seem to be a good way to determine if the root logger is off.  I need to know this from an auditing perspective to determine if there has been some tampering.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the root logger and ask for the state:

```
LoggerFactory.getLogger("root").isDebugEnabled()
```

Comment: so will it come back as null of rootLogger is off?  I need to check if it has been disabled.